# Can we have a "pump specification for newbies" Q&A

Tags: discussion

I actually started one, then deleted because I was unsure. The question would be along the lines of:

> We get lots of naive question on pumps and pumping systems. This site could use a concise guide to help these people get started.
> **what are the first steps in selecting and specifying a pump?**

My answer would be "write down medium, flowrate and system curve or pressure diff. and find an appropriate centrifugal pump, if no centrifugal pump fits investigate other pump types" in a few more words.

However, when starting on an answer, I felt that a few things need consideration:

- it's a huge subject: A concise getting started guide necessarily leaves out a lot. For an experienced engineer I will be obvious what was left out, for the target audience, not so much.
- OTOH, *some* questions clearly would benefit from even such a bareboned guide

Ultimately, is such a Q&A something we (or rather some of us) want for this site, what should be the scope and most importantly who would put work into an answer?

Comment: As you mention, it may be hard to make an answer that is both helpful and broad. There are lots of topics that come up every once in a while that would benefit from a "you must understand this much before proceeding" limit. I'm not sure that StackExchange is set up to have such a system.

Comment: The alternative would be a meta question "What information should I include in my question" with one answer each for several common types of question. A lot of questions here would greatly benefit from simply writing down the relevant explanation and including a sketch.